# Are there any virtual IoT simulators that facilitate the connection with Ethereum Blockchain?

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, ether, iot

I already built a smart contract for Ethereum Blockchain by using truffle; Now, I'm looking to connect my smart contract with the IoT environment.

So are there any IoT simulators (platform, framework, etc.) that facilitate the connection with the Ethereum Blockchain without using physical material?

Answer (score 0):

For most IoT project incorporating Smart Contracts, one will make use of an external oracle to input data into the Smart Contract.

Try http://www.oraclize.it/

Hope this helps